# Water/Solvents sprayed into running intake to clean carbon deposits?

Tags: toyota, air-intake, 4runner, carb-cleaner

Recently performed a top engine cleaning using seafoam.  After reading about this more, learned this isn't new, and variations such as using water instead have been around for a long time.  Interested to know others results from using either water or some other product.  Does water work as well or better than seafoam?

Car ran so much better after doing this, made me want to reroute my windshield washer fluid so I can do it while driving down the road.  :)  (joking)

Comment: My v8 ran better in wet weather due to the increased humidity, but controlling the delivery may need a second injection system.

Comment: Hard to beat seafoam, water injection works, but can cause rust on the cylinder walls and other steel parts if you do a lot of short run driving,